# SQl Update with IF else statement

Tags: mysql

I want to update "status" column. I wanted to use UPDATE with IF condition something like this:

```
UPDATE rent_record 
 SET status = IF(status='pending', borrowed, IF(status='returnP', returned) ) 
WHERE WHERE ID='$name'
```

I am not sure if it'll be possible. Please suggest the best possible ways to do this.
Thank you

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem, please mark it accepted. It helps other users looking for similar solutions and you will gain reputation. If not, please provide more information to help answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CASE`:

```
UPDATE rent_record 
SET status = CASE WHEN status = 'pending' THEN 'borrowed'
                  WHEN status = 'returnP' THEN 'returned'
                  ELSE ...
             END
WHERE ID=?
```

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE rent_record SET status= CASE WHEN status = 'pending' THEN ='borrowed' ELSE 'returned' END WHERE ID='$name';";

i tried this. but it doesnt work

Comment: Try this: `$sql = "UPDATE rent_record SET status= CASE WHEN status = 'pending' THEN 'borrowed' ELSE 'returned' END WHERE ID='$name';";` , you had a syntax error: (additional `=` after `THEN`), also always use prepared statements! like in the answer.

Comment: No, _don't_ try that, use a prepared statement in your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost right, you need to add an `else` value for the second `IF`, which should probably be `status` i.e.:

```
UPDATE rent_record 
SET status = IF(status='pending', 'borrowed', IF(status='returnP', 'returned', status)) 
WHERE ID='$name'
```